# Split svg image in multiple paths

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am totally new to inkscape and can't figure it out how to solve this problem and I could not find help anywhere.

I need to split this SVG image which is only one path into regions as drawn.

How can I do this?

[image]

Edit: I want that each part outlined with black to be separated into another path because curently everything is a single path.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a little? If I understand you correctly, all the black lines in your image are currently a single path. Do you want to turn them into a single solid black circle, with white shapes on top of it where the holes currently are, or something else?

Comment: Also, the reason you can't comment on your own question is because you've accidentally logged in with [two](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/75414/marcus) different [accounts](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/75417/marcus). (Maybe you used a different OpenID to log in?) You might want to [get your accounts merged](/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, all the black lines in your image are currently a single filled path, and you want to turn them into a single solid black circle with white shapes on top of it.  If so, you can do it like this:

1. Select the path.
2. From the *Path* menu, select *Break Apart* (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).
3. You now have a bunch of black shapes on top of a black circle.  Select them all (e.g. by dragging over them) and deselect the circle if it got selected.
4. Using the color palette at the bottom of the window (or the stroke and fill dialog), set the fill color of the inner shapes to white.
5. If some of the inner shapes don't show up, they might be *under* the black circle.  To fix this, raise them to the top by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> while they're still selected (or select *Raise to Top* from the *Object* menu, or just press the "Raise to Top" toolbar button).  Alternatively, you can select the black circle and lower it until all the white shapes are visible.

You may also want to redraw the black outer circle, to turn it into an actual circle object instead of a Bézier path, and maybe redraw or at least simplify the inner shapes to get rid of unnecessary control points.

In fact, one option (especially if the original path was traced from a bitmap, and looks bad at high magnification) would be to simply redraw the whole thing from scratch.  This should not be particularly difficult: all you need is one black circle, a bunch of white rectangles on top of it, and another slightly smaller circle to intersect the rectangles with.  You may want to use guides or a grid to get the rectangles precisely lined up.  To get the circles perfectly concentric, a useful trick is to draw one circle, duplicate it, and then adjust its radius.